# Composer keeps reinstalling the same core version

Tags: composer

I manually updated a Drupal 9 installation to 9.1.2. I need to install the  [Real AES](https://www.drupal.org/project/real_aes) module, which depends on the [Defuse PHP-Encryption](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) library.

I attempted to install it using Composer, but it tries to update Drupal to 9.1.2 again, which breaks it, and I have to restore from a backup.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Running `composer --no-plugins --no-scripts require defuse/php-encryption` causes the following error.

> PHP Warning:  Module 'pdo_mysql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
> Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
>
> Continue as root/super user [yes]?
>
> Using version ^2.2 for defuse/php-encryption
> ./composer.json has been updated
> Running composer update defuse/php-encryption
>
> Loading composer repositories with package information
>
> Updating dependencies
>
> Lock file operations: 2 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
>
> - Locking defuse/php-encryption (v2.2.1)
> - Locking paragonie/random_compat (v9.99.100)
>
> Writing lock file
>
> Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
> Package operations: 3 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
>
> - Installing paragonie/random_compat (v9.99.100): Extracting archive
> - Installing defuse/php-encryption (v2.2.1): Extracting archive
> - Installing drupal/core (9.1.2): Extracting archive
>
> 1 package suggestions were added by new dependencies, use `composer suggest` to see details.
>
> Package doctrine/reflection is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use roave/better-reflection instead.
>
> Generating autoload files

Comment: What do you mean by "I manually updated my Drupal9 install to v9.1.2"?

Comment: And what do you mean by "my Drupal is broken"? What error messages do you see?

Comment: I will run it now and share the webpage the appears. Also, someone wrote back to me on Github and explained why this is happening.  (See link at top of the post)

Comment: An error occurred.

Sorry, the page you are looking for is currently unavailable.
Please try again later.

If you are the system administrator of this resource then you should check the error log for details.

Faithfully yours, nginx.

Comment: @bforest please check drupal logs to get more technical error message

Comment: Why are you using `--no-plugins` and `--no-scripts`? The person replying on github says this is happening because you're using `--no-plugins`

Comment: Composer says use "--no-plugins and --no-scripts" if running as root.  Also, the person gave 2 reasons for the issue.  The first being something about the wrong drupal/core directory.

- - - - - - ->8 - ACCESS.LOG
xx.xx.xx.xx - - [11/Jan/2021:20:33:54 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 326 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac  OS X 10.12; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0"
xx.xx.xx.xx - - [11/Jan/2021:20:33:55 -0500] "GET /core/install.php HTTP/1.1" 500 494 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0"

Comment: - - - - - - ->8 - ERROR.LOG
2021/01/11 20:33:55 [error] 36458#100381: *486 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare format_size() (previously declared in /usr/local/www/drupal9/core/includes/common.inc:136) in /usr/local/www/drupal9/vendor/drupal/core/includes/common.inc on line 136" while reading response header from upstream, client: xx.xx.xx.xx, server: drupalsite.info, request: "GET /core/install.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock:", host: "drupalsite.info:443"

Comment: This is failing because you're running composer with the `--no-plugins` option. That flag is breaking this. It is put quite clearly in your linked issue on github. Don't run the command with that flag. You say you're using these flags because composer says to use them if you run as root, so don't run as root.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.  I was able to modify my "www" user and su to my "www" user and then run the composer without the -- arguments and... ...it worked.

Comment: @bforest If you found the answer, you can write an answer to your own question; this is helpful for future visitors to the site who may have a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved.  I was running Composer as root and disabling scripts and plugins because of that.

In my over concern for security, I didn't think to just enable my servers "www" user to allow for access via "su www".  Sometimes you just need a good SHAKE!

> "Don't run the command with that flag. You say you're using these
> flags because composer says to use them if you run as root, so don't
> run as root.
> – sonfd 12 hours ago"

Thank you for your feedback. I was able to modify my "www" user and su to my "www" user and then run the composer without the -- arguments and... ...it worked.
– bforest 11 hours ago

@bforest If you found the answer, you can write an answer to your own question; this is helpful for future visitors to the site who may have a similar problem.
– Patrick Kenny 5 hours ago.